# "Donate to this plugin" for WordPress.org Plugin Authors

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wordpress.org

I recently saw a link titled **"Donate to this plugin >"** link on a WordPress theme (and then I did!). How is this added to a plugin's page on wordpress.org?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of "donate to this plugin" on WordPress.org]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is read from the infos on your plugins readme.txt. Example from my [Default Values for Attachments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-values-for-attachments/)

> === Plugin Name ===
>
> Contributors: moraleida.me
>
> Donate link: http://moraleida.me/
>
> Tags: attachments, default values, caption, title, description
>
> Requires at least: 2.5 Tested up to: 3.3.2 Stable
>
> tag: 0.1 License: GPLv2 or later License URI:
>
> http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html